# How to plot overlapping images with matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, overlay

I have several dataset matrices `x`, `y`, and`z`, where `z` contains values at the positions `x,y` showing shifted (overlapping) parts of the same picture. x and y are rectangularly centered around different center positions for each dataset.

How can I combine the data in one plot using `pcolor` or similar? Note that it should be a rectangular plot in the end, but that not all data points are given due to the shift.

Comment: You might be able to work something with transparency via [`alpha`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alpha.html). (Also a small example could be useful for people to play with).

Comment: `imfuse`? `imshowpair`?

Comment: Thank you! It was not necessary to use transparency as the question was just about how to plot several data sets into the same figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now solved my own question by using the command `hold on`, which makes it possible to plot several times into the same figure. You just have to run it in between two plot commands.